# Convert to UTF-8

Tags: android, character-encoding, urlconnection

I'm using the following method to read a txt file from an HTTP server.

```
public static String getHtmlFromUrl(String strUrl, String referer, boolean isMobile) {
    URL url = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String returnValue = "";

    try {
        url = new URL(strUrl);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

        // force server to mimic specific Browser
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
        if(isMobile)
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgentMobile);

        con.setRequestProperty("Referer", referer);

        con.setReadTimeout(15000);
        con.connect();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        returnValue = sb.toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I don't have direct access to this file (so I cannot change the way it is). If I call the URL in the browser, it shows up correctly using ISO-8859 or Windows-1252 encoding.

Android seems to be interpreting it as utf-8 by default. So I need a way to convert the `returnValue` or the `StringBuffer sb` from the existing ISO-8859 encoding to utf-8.

How do I do this?

Comment: `new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")` is a way to define the encoding of the input. Take a look at the Doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update  This line:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

needs to be:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.getInputStream(), "ISO_8859_1"));
```

or since Java 7:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
```

**UPDATE:**
ISO_8859_1 in place of UTF-8

Comment: This (of course) doesn't work, because the text is in ISO-8859. But the hint was great. If you update your answer I will accept it. `reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));`

Comment: how I missed that .... sorry for that part .I have updated as you suggested

Comment: not quite ... seems like some copy/paste issue is still there :-)

Comment: yes I have updated that refresh again from your side

Comment: DO you need any more update  o this question or it resolved your problem (hint :-))??